# Calculate possible no of combination with two digits with n length

Tags: python, combinations

Looking for a formula to calculate possible number of combinations with 'K' length with two digits lets say as 'a' & 'b'.

**Example:**
No of a & b with length 'k' can be used in combinations. And we need only combinations count which are starting with b.

```
k = 6 (Length)
a = 3
b = 3
Here answer will be : 9

k = 7 (Length)
a = 4
b = 3
Here answer will be : 15
Here is the list of combinations possible for example
bbbaaaa
bbabaaa
bbaabaa
bbaaaba
bbaaaab
babbaaa
bababaa
babaaba
babaaab
baabbaa
baababa
baabaab
baaabba
baaabab
baaaabb
```

above mentioned answers are calculated manually. I am looking for this formula to calculate with large numbers.

Any one here can help me with this. Looking for a python code which are be accurate and fast.

Comment: I don't understand the first example. If `a = 3` and `b = 3`, the only combination with length 6 is `666666`.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: @Barmar Hie, I had mentioned example with above for better understanding.

Comment: Oh, those are the counts of `a` and `b`, that wasn't clear.

Comment: I am trying to solve above issue with multiple ways and failed with it, that is the thing i am here with stackoverflow for some solution or suggestion.

Comment: Add your failing code. Then we'll help you understand what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Your second example doesn't seem to be complete. You're missing the reverses of all the permutations.

Comment: FYI, when order matters, they're permutations, not combinations.

Comment: i need only possible combinations with mentioned no of digits and which starts with 'b'

Comment: If they all start with `b` then that initial `b` is a red herring from a counting point of view. Concentrate on counting the number of ways that the rest of the string can be formed. In any event -- this isn't a programming problem at all, so why ask on this forum?

Comment: If you only care about the permutations that start with `b`, you can just ignore the first character in the result. Subtract 1 from `b` and calculate the number of permutations.

Comment: i am a new to coding and these stuffs who is learning few things. you can help me to get this solved?

Comment: @Barmar it is usefully thought of as a combinations problem. In effect, the `a`s are choosing a combination of positions.

Comment: The answer is just `C(k-1,a)`. In python: `math.comb(k-1,a)`

Comment: @JohnColeman This worked, Thank you.

Comment: One of your pieces of data is redundant.  a length, b length, total length.  you can omit one.  Then just chose a or b, and find how many different combinations digit positions that they can occupy in the final number.

Comment: @JohnColeman When using `math.comb(k-1, a)` with the first example (`k = 6`, `a = 3`) the result comes out as 10.

Comment: @RoyCohen As it should. OP miscounted when they came up with 9.

Comment: Then the quesion should be edited.

Comment: @RoyCohen If anything, the question should be closed.